# Invalid Authentication Scheme error with libgit2sharp

Tags: .net-core, libgit2sharp

We have been using LibGit2sharp from our .net core application to interact (clone, commit,push ) with git hosted in bitbucket. We use DefaultCredentials class (https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp/DefaultCredentials.cs) for CredentialsProvider property of CloneOptions. we use http url for clone git repo.

```
CloneOptions co= new CloneOptions() {BranchName="Master", 
CredentialsProvider= (_url,_user, cred) }=> new CredentialsProvider() }

Repository.Clone(cloneUrl,workingDir,co);
```

It was working all well in our dev servers, but is giving Invalid Authentication Scheme error in our QA environment. I am not really sure what to look into here. Any lead will be of a great help.

I tried to get the details of OS and patches of the windows servers where this application is running. Our infra team says that there are no changes in both dev and QA servers, both are exactly having same OS , patches applied , all other congigurations.